# Was the wheel invented before the wall?

Tags: history, technology

So, this extraordinary claim has been getting a lot of publicity lately:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQKrfGCd7I8

> They say a wall is medieval, well so is a wheel. A wheel is older than a wall. And I looked at every single car out there, even the really expensive ones the secret service use. And believe me, they are expensive. I said "do they all have wheels?". "Yes". "Oh, I thought it was medieval." The wheel is older than the wall, you know that?
>
> Donald Trump, 45th President of the United States of America

I'm pretty sure I know about this, but was the wall invented before, or after the wheel?

Answer (score 130):

**No, walls predate wheels by several millenia.**

The invention of the wheel is [generally placed at around 3500-4500 BCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel). However walls were [famously built around the town of Jericho in 8000-9000BCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_of_Jericho), so they are at least that old.

More information can be found here: https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2019/01/10/president-trump-is-wheel-older-than-wall/2539339002/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88333/discussion-on-answer-by-djclayworth-was-the-wheel-invented-before-the-wall).